# Any Difference Between (int) 1 and 1 in PHP?

Tags: php, casting

I was reading some code that a consultant provided us. It's a bit convoluted, and at the end of a function, it reads:

```
return (int) 1;
```

Instead of:

```
return 1;
```

PHP has a lot of magic in it; is this as bone-headed as it looks, or is there a valid reason to cast an integer as an integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's the same. `1` is an integer literal.

See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) these are all integer literals; casting to `int` has no effect:

```
$a = 1234; // decimal number
$a = -123; // a negative number
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
$a = 0x1A; // hexadecimal number (equivalent to 26 decimal)
```

If you did `return "1";` that would be an entirely different matter. There are some differences in behaviour between `"1"` (string) and `1` (int), namely with [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php).

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty bone headed. Integer literals are, well... integers.

`1 === 1` however `1 !== '1'`

also, when necessary, (*as in this case it definitely isn't*) I would suggest not typecasting with `(int)` use `intval()` instead.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't clear: I would suggest not typecasting with (int) use intval() instead.

Comment: consider: `echo (int) 97.6 * 0.5; //prints 48.5` vs `echo intval(97.6 * 0.5); //prints 48`